# How to test iOS 7 microphone privacy code (privacy setting cannot be removed from device)

Tags: ios

Background: My app wants to access the microphone. Under iOS 7, microphone access is controlled by Privacy in the Settings app, on a per-app basis. The VERY FIRST TIME my app requests access to the microphone, the iOS 7 system will prompt the user whether to allow such access. My code has to be able to handle either response well, and therefore I must be able to test my app under such circumstances.

Now, it could happen that my initial code does not work as intended, so I would need to test this again (and again, and again, …), however, as pointed out above, the system prompt only occurs the very first time my app requests access, and subsequently the system just silently either grants or denies the access, based on the setting in Settings > Privacy > Microphone.

Problem: This would all be fine if only I could delete my app from the device, and try again, with the system also having deleted the privacy setting for my app, so that the system will prompt again. But apparently iOS 7 remembers the microphone privacy setting, even after the app has been deleted, so that when the app is re-installed, it obtains the old privacy setting, and the system never prompts the user whether to allow microphone access. This means I cannot test that part of my code. I suppose I can do a complete factory reset of the device, every time, but that's a bit cumbersome. This is happening with iOS 7.0.4. Any ideas on how to best deal with this?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the answer there may also apply here. I will test that as soon as my factory reset has completed:-)

Comment: Yes, the answer to the question about calendar access also applies here. Thanks @rmaddy! Excellent, much easier even than deleting the app. So what is the right etiquette here? I already up voted the other Q&A, but do I just leave my own question sitting here as a close duplicate? Or should I do something with it (delete it)? Can I officially mark the other answer as the right answer also to this question?

Comment: Just leave your question be. It will get closed as a duplicate (eventually). If someone else searches for how to reset the microphone privacy they will find this and see the answer in the duplicate.