# Remove iOS7 Microphone permission in order to test permission decline

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

New in iOS7 (I believe) the user must give permission for the app to use the microphone. This is a similar request as when the app wants to get location information.

I was asked once for permission. Now, I'd like to test my app to see how it reacts when the user declines this permission. I've deleted the app from the phone, but I'm not asked for permission again.

Any idea how to clear this permission over and over so that I may test when this permission is requested and how the app reacts when it's denied.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005368/how-to-test-ios-7-microphone-privacy-code-privacy-setting-cannot-be-removed-fro?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355039/testing-permissions-for-microphone-push-in-ios-app?rq=1 which are both listed under the Related section of your question. Please check those before you submit your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location and Privacy

Answer (score -3):

Go to privacy section of the settings app, there will be an option for microphone, turn 'off' your app. Then kill you app and start fresh.

Comment: This does not cause the permission to be asked, just disables the permission: Microphone input permission refused - will record only silence is the output. I'm looking to have the app ask for permission and test the denial, not just deny the permission.